# Is running a nodejs application as root dangerous in all cases, or only when it's exposed to the web?

Tags: root, node.js

I've heard over and over again that it's dangerous to run a nodejs application as root, but I'm curious, does that apply to personal applications for administrative purposes on a home computer, or is it only when an application is open to web traffic?

For example, if I wanted to create a node application to manage processes for multiple users on my personal computer, would that carry the same risks?

Answer (score 0):

Yourself !

For your example, let's say you introduced a bug that under some circumstances, do a `kill init` a `rm -rf /` or write a 1Mb file to /dev/sda....

If ran under a normal user, then no problem.
If ran under root, your computer may reboot (kill init) or stop working and become unusable after reboot (rm -rf /, writing on /dev/sda).

Look at SSH daemon: at startup, it does the privileged actions it needs to start and then drop privileges to run under a dedicated user.